# What's the proper way to initialize an Android application?

Tags: android

Problem: I need to run some code at every start before my app is ready to be used.

At first, I tried doing it in a dedicated activity.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" />

<activity android:name=".StarterActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

AppLoader.java

```
public class AppLoader {

    private static Object someInstance;

    public static void load(Runnable onCompleteCallback) {
        try {
            someInstance = new Object();

            //potentially long operation to initialize the app
            Thread.sleep(5000);

            onCompleteCallback.run();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static void checkInitialized() {
        if (someInstance == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Not initialized");
        }
    }
}
```

StarterActivity.java

```
public class StarterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        AppLoader.load(() -> {
            MainActivity.start(this);
            finish();
        });
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static void start(Context context) {
        Intent starter = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(starter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        AppLoader.checkInitialized();
    }
}
```

This works fine if the app is cold started via the launcher icon but crashes in all other cases. Simple way to reproduce the issue:

1. Go to developer settings on your device and set "Background process limit" to "No background process"
2. Open the app
3. Open some other app
4. Open the app again. Result: it crashes.

Here's an article describing a similar problem: [Android process death — and the (big) implications for your app](https://medium.com/inloopx/android-process-kill-and-the-big-implications-for-your-app-1ecbed4921cb)

Possible solutions:

1. Lazy loading/reactive approach. I try to use it as much as possible but there is always some code I need to run in a blocking way before user can interact with the app so this is not enough.
2. Putting all of that code in App.onCreate(). This would probably work for small apps but I've seen large apps that take 5-10 seconds to initialize, and I doubt they use onCreate() for that. Possible downsides: ANR and/or excessive startup time in Android Vitals?
3. Checking if the app is initialized in a BaseActivity, but that would require either blocking onCreate or managing lifecycle callbacks manually which doesn't sound like a good idea.

So, what's the proper way to run some code every time the app is launched?

Note: Normally StarterActivity would be a splash screen, AppLoader would be injected, etc, but I left that out for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
    android:name=".AppLoader"
```

**AppLoader.java**

```
public class AppLoader extends Application {

private static Object someInstance;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    // DO YOUR STUFF 
}
}
```

**Update**
- Use `Handler` with splash screen.

```
public class StarterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Handler handler;
    private Runnable myStuffRunnable;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        handler = new Handler();
        myStuffRunnable = new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                // DO MY STUFF
                MainActivity.start(this);
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        handler.removeCallbacks(myStuffRunnable);
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        handler.post(myStuffRunnable);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        handler.removeCallbacks(myStuffRunnable);
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: But what if "do your stuff" takes 5-10 seconds? I'm suspecting at the very least that would cause "excessive startup time" in Android Vitals, and possibly ANR too. Or not?
I guess what I'm trying to do is 1) Make it seem like the app is responsive while loading it (splash screen) 2) But not sure how to handle cases when the process is killed in background.

Comment: If you expect your stuff takes long time then use `IntentService` and register to on baseActivity. But if only 5-10 sec then use `Handler` on splash screen.

Comment: Check my answer update with `Handler` and that will enable you to make some progress animation for good user experience  until you do your stuff.

Comment: Maybe I didn't word my question correctly but it wasn't about threading/updating ui/etc, I was trying to find the best way to execute some code at every start (but not in onCreate of App). The Handler solution would still crash if the user opened MainActivity directly. For that reason, I ended up just redirecting to StarterActivity if needed. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your app is throwing the RuntimeException you set in AppLoader.checkInitialized() method, because your someInstance object is losing it's state when the app goes to background and gets killed by the system ('cause you have set your device to hold zero background threads). So, when you try to reopen the app, the system launches MainActivity directly (and not StarterActivity) because it is trying to restore it's previous state. But variables are not restored, not even static variables.

So, if you need the Object someInstance on your MainActivity, you should integrate it's instantiation into MainActivitie's lifecycle, overriding methods like onSavedInstanceState, onRestoreInstanceState, etc, to properly handle and reaload this object if your app gets killed by the system.

Take a look on this https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

Answer (score 0):

If anyone's interested, I ended up just redirecting the user to `StarterActivity` if needed to make sure the necessary code is executed at every start.

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private boolean isCreated;

    @Override
    protected final void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (!appLoader.isLoaded()) {
            StarterActivity.start(this);
            finish();
            return;
        }

        onCreateActivity(savedInstanceState);
        isCreated = true;
    }

    protected void onCreateActivity(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    }

    @Override
    protected final void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (isCreated) {
            onDestroyActivity();
        }
    }

    protected void onDestroyActivity() {
    }

}
```

All activities extend `BaseActivity` (except `StarterActivity`) and override `onCreateActivity`/`onDestroyActivity` instead of `onCreate`/`onDestroy`.